# How to make method calls and v-shows work from outside Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

We are using Vue.js to implement the popup function.
The "Click" button in the Vue App will launch the popup correctly, but the following example
vueApp.methods.openModal() /// call from outside
The popup does not appear when I call from outside, although the function call itself is possible. Why is this? Also, how can I make v-show work properly when calling a method from outside Vue like this?

xxx.html

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="openModal">Click</button>
  <div id="dbg_overlay" v-show="showContent" v-on:click="closeModal">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <button v-on:click="closeModal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

xxx.js

```
const vueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      showContent: false,
    }
  },
        
  methods: {
    openModal: function() {
      this.showContent = true
    },
    closeModal: function() {
      this.showContent = false
    }
  },  
};
      
Vue.createApp(lessonScheduleEdit).mount("#app");

vueApp.methods.openModal() /// call from outside
```

vue I am using :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need the following:**

1. assign your Vue app to a variable, available anywhere in global scope.
2. once you make it available, to call a method defined as `methodName` in its `method`s, you have to call it directly (e.g: `myVar.methodName()`, ***not as*** `myVar.methods.methodName()` ***!!!***)

**How to make the variable globally available:**

The most common method to declare globally available variables would be to use the `window` object:

```
window.myVueApp = Vue.createApp(vueApp).mount("#app");

// from anywhere else in the window:
window.myVueApp.openModal();
```

A more modern way of making a variable globally available is to use `window`'s alias: `globalThis`:

```
globalThis.myVueApp = Vue.createApp(vueApp).mount('#app');

// both of these will now work 
// because, inside a browser, globalThis === window
window.myVueApp.openModal();
globalThis.myVueApp.openModal();
```

Note: can I use [globalThis](https://caniuse.com/?search=globalThis)?
But, even though `window` now has a fancy new alias, using it is just as bad (read why below).

---

**Note:** *Polluting the global scope with variables is generally regarded as **bad practice***, as it runs the risk of name collisions (when both your code and someone else's, used on same page, accidentally use the same global scope variable names).

Ultimately, this means that, at least in theory, your code is unreliable (it might fail under certain circumstances). Ideally you want to write unbreakable code, which does not interfere with (break) anything else running on same page, at any point.

To minimize this naming collision risk, you could actually place your app inside the `Vue` namespace, which is already available in global scope, as we already know the Vue namespace does not have a `myVueApp` property (and the likelihood that anyone else would also use `Vue.myVueApp` on your page is negligible):

```
Vue.myVueApp = // ...your app here...
```

See it working:

```js
const vueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      showContent: false,
    }
  },
        
  methods: {
    openModal: function() {
      this.showContent = true
    },
    closeModal: function() {
      this.showContent = false
    }
  },
};
      
Vue.myModeratelyAmazingVueApp = Vue.createApp(vueApp).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="openModal">Click</button>
  <div id="dbg_overlay" v-show="showContent" @click="closeModal">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <button @click="closeModal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="Vue.myModeratelyAmazingVueApp.openModal()">external open</button>
```

Comment: Thanks to your code, I was able to achieve what I wanted to. Thank you very much.
I would also like to thank you very much for the design aspects of the coding!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `v-if` and check if your defined value is equal to `true`. Like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false"> 
    <!-- Your content in here -->
  </modal>
</div>
```

you can also do `showModal = true` inside of your methods, just like this:

```
methods: {
  clickModal() {   //just renamed in template it's @click="clickModal()"
    showModal = true;
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you, can I call this from out of Vue scope?? I still don't have any idea how can I do it...